# MIPI Bridge 2.5Gbps or Above

Tags: fpga, interface, bridge, data-acquisition

I was looking for some MIPI bridge solution and mostly found MIPI to LVDS Bridge. But the problem with LVDS is that it can't support more than 1.2Gbps.

I was looking for some solution which can support 2.5Gbps or above. Even MIPI to parallel bridge will work fine to me. As the output of bridge I was planning to interface with FPGA. My FPGA can support 150MHz of clock per pin.

Can someone suggest such solution if available?

Thanks,

Sanjeev

Answer (score 1):

A quick search of MIPI DSI/CSI-2 to Parallel Bridge will show you solutions related to the Lattice Semiconductor CrossLink.

If there are transceivers on your FPGA, you could use the Meticom solution and use their PHY to convert incoming SLVS MIPI signals to high speed signaling supported by Xilinx/Altera transceivers (2.5Gbps max conversion speed). Using the Meticom solution will require you to write your own core, or buy a MIPI core that uses transceivers, both which are expensive either in time, or money.

Good luck in your design process.

Comment: Yeah we have both the solution, however the problem is that they can supprt only upto 2.5Gbps which you have also mentioned. I was looking for something similar with higher speed may be upto 3.3Gbps.